# Deleting large number of files

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm writing a script to delete large number of files in linux. The script will run every two minutes in crontab. I tried using the
 `find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f  -name "*.pcap" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt | tail -$del | awk '{print $8}'`

and saving this to a variable and tried to delete using `rm`  command, but dint run. I have found out that `find . -type f -delete`   can be used to delete the files, but I don't know how to add this part to my command. How would I do this?

Comment: I assume want to delete all but *n* files (because of the `tail -$del`? If you could replace that with another condition that `find` supports (for example delete all files that are older than *n* minutes/hours/days old), this would be solvable with a pure `find ... -delete`.

Comment: Why are you doing this? If there are lots of garbage files, can't you inhibit their creating in the first place? If they are consumed by something else, arrange for the consumer to get rid of them when done? Use pipes to ship data around instead of files?

Comment: @vonbrand, good point. `dumpcap` also has provision to create a cyclic traffic dump.

Answer (score 3):

```
#! /bin/zsh -
del=10
rm -f /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/*.pcap(D.Om[1,$del])
```

That's using `zsh` globbing qualifiers:

- `D`: includes hidden files (**D**ot files).
- `.`: only regular files (like `find`'s `-type f`)
- `Om`: reverse **O**rder on the age (based on **m**odification time)
- `[1,$del]`: only include the first `$del` files.

With GNU tools:

```
cd /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ &&
  find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pcap' -type f -printf '%T@@%p\0' |
    sort -zn | sed -z "s/[^@]*@//;$del q" | xargs -r0 rm -f
```

`find` builds a NUL delimited list of filenames with a Unix timestamp prepended (like `1390682991.0859627500@./file`) which is sorted by `sort`. `sed` removes the timestamp and quits after reading `$del` records. That's passed as arguments to `rm` using `xargs -r0`.

or:

```
cd /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ &&
  find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pcap' -type f -printf '%T@@%p\0' |
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | sort -n | head -n "$del" |
    cut -d@ -f2- | tr  '\0\n' '\n\0' | xargs -r0 rm -f
```

Same, except that we're using `cut` to remove the timestamp and `head` to select the first `$del` lines. Because GNU `cut` and `head` don't support a `-z` to work on NUL delimited records, we use `tr` to swap the newline and NUL characters before and after feeding  the data to them.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done painlessly in bash by combining `find -exec` with a temporary file. Unfortunately this requires running find twice - once to count the files, and once again to remove all but *n* files. Note that `$FIND | wc -l` will not count properly for filenames including `\n`.

```
FIND="find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -name "*.pcap" -type f -maxdepth 1"
$FIND | wc -l > delcount.tmp
$FIND -exec bash -c 'DELCOUNT=$(cat delcount.tmp) ; if [ $DELCOUNT -gt 5 ] ; then echo {}; echo $(( $DELCOUNT - 1 )) > delcount.tmp ; fi' ';'
rm delcount.tmp
```